# Show title of article instead of date in a Views block

Tags: views

I'm using the Views module to show a list of the 3 most recent articles posted on a site. I've set the filter granularity to the specific date of posting and it shows three dates with bullet points in the block. What I would I like to do is get rid of the Bullet points, have the date formatted MM/DD/YYYY and then on the line below the date have the link to the article where the link is the title of the article.

I want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cflmv.png) to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPAkF.png), where TEXT is the title of the article it links to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Create new date format as you want (MM/DD/YYYY).
      admin/config/regional/date-time/formats
2. Create Date type and assign your format.
      admin/config/regional/date-time
3. In views: Select your date type under "Choose how users view dates and times:" when you add your date field under "FIELDS".
4. Add (Content:title)title field (after date field) and Enable the Link this field to the original piece of content checkbox.
5. Bullet point from your css

Comment: I can't figure out how to show just three without using the Contextual Filter. How can I get it to show just three of them?

Comment: check under "PAGER" 1. click on use pager . 2. select "Display a specified number of items" radio button. 3. set "Items per page" as 3 left "Offset" 0

Comment: Nevermind. I figured out I could use the pager to limit the number of items shown.